# Why is C++ ShowWindow() not working properly when hiding a window and showing another?

Tags: c++, winapi, window, showwindow

I am writing my first Win32 app in C++ and I am trying to create 3 windows between which to redirect based on what buttons the user clicks on. I initialised the windows (*window1,window2,window3*) as children of the main window *hwnd* and only set *window1* as visible. *window1* also has two buttons, each of which is supposed to direct either to *window2* or *window3*.

I tried to hide *window1* and show which window I want to switch to using the *ShowWindow()* function. However, it is not working (clicking the buttons does nothing). Could you help me understand why?

On another piece of code I had before, where I had not created window1, and the buttons and the other two windows were just children of hwnd, pressing the button did show the right window, but the button remained there, even if it did not belong on that window.

Also, is there a more efficient way of switching between windows (without deleting and creating them again and again?

Thanks!!!

EDIT: I managed to solve my problem. It arose from the fact that I had declared windows 1,2 and 3 as static. By declaring them under the same class as hwnd, I was able to process the messages from the buttons under the main WindowProcedure(). Since my program is gonna be quite simple, I do not need to create a different procedure for the new windows, but thanks to the comments, now I also know how to do that!

```cpp
    LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        switch (message)
        {
            case WM_CREATE:
    
                window1 = CreateWindow("STATIC","Window 1",WS_VISIBLE|WS_BORDER|WS_CHILD,0,0,600,600,hwnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
                window2 = CreateWindow("STATIC","Window 2",WS_BORDER|WS_CHILD,0,0,600,600,hwnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
                button2 = CreateWindow(
                                       "BUTTON",
                                       "SECOND WINDOW",
                                       WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER,
                                       350, 480,
                                       200, 20,
                                       window1, (HMENU) 2, NULL, NULL);
                window3 = CreateWindow("STATIC","Window 3",WS_BORDER|WS_CHILD,0,0,600,600,hwnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
                button3 = CreateWindow(
                                       "BUTTON",
                                       "THIRD WINDOW",
                                       WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER,
                                       50, 480,
                                       200, 20,
                                       window1, (HMENU) 3, NULL, NULL);
                break;
    
            case WM_COMMAND:
    
                switch(LOWORD(wParam))
                {
                    case 2:
                        ShowWindow(window1,SW_HIDE);
                        ShowWindow(window2,SW_SHOW);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        ShowWindow(window1,SW_HIDE);
                        ShowWindow(window3,SW_SHOW);
                        break;
                }
    
            break;
            case WM_DESTROY:
                PostQuitMessage (0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
                break;
            default:                      /* for messages that we don't deal with */
                return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I think you are meant to check the notification code. It's in the high word of `wParam`, and you are looking for `BM_CLICKED`. It's all described in the documentation, which is worth a re-read I suspect: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/button-messages

Comment: I really doubt that your wndproc receive WM_COMMAND message, because button 2 and button 3 are children of the window 1.

Comment: Your switch  statement is also missing a `break`; if it did receive the message, it would show windows 2 *and* 3 when you clicked on the button  for 2

Comment: @user2120666 why is that? does the button need to be a child of hwnd in order to receive a WM_COMMAND message?

Comment: Sure, because your wndproc is window procedure for your main window, nothing else

Comment: @user253751 thanks, fixed it now!

Comment: @MaraPostolache Notification messages are sent the window's parent.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan how would I get the notification on window1 then? all I know is how to use the WindowProcedure function to process messages

Comment: @MaraPostolache well either the main window has to be the parent, or you have to write the window procedure for window1.

Comment: @MaraPostolache See [Subclassing Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview) for writing window procedures for child controls that you don't register custom classes for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a new `window1` as in the steps of creating the main form.

Then create a `windowprocessforwindow1` for `window1`, process the `WM_COMMAND` message in this function.

Here is the sample:

```
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
LRESULT CALLBACK windowprocessforwindow1(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
static HWND  window1, window2, button2, window3, button3;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT("hello windows");
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASS wndclass;
    wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;
    if (!RegisterClass(&wndclass))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("This program requires Windows NT!"), szAppName, MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindow(szAppName,
        TEXT("the hello program"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while (GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        static HINSTANCE hInstance;
        static WNDCLASSEX win1;
    case WM_CREATE:
        hInstance = (HINSTANCE)::GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE);
        win1.hInstance = hInstance;
        win1.lpszClassName = L"Window 1";
        win1.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)windowprocessforwindow1;      /* This function is called by windows */
        win1.style = CS_DBLCLKS;                 /* Catch double-clicks */
        win1.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
        win1.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
        win1.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
        win1.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
        win1.lpszMenuName = NULL;                 /* No menu */
        win1.cbClsExtra = 0;                      /* No extra bytes after the window class */
        win1.cbWndExtra = 0;                      /* structure or the window instance */
        win1.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_BACKGROUND;
        if (!RegisterClassEx(&win1))
            return 0;
        window1 = CreateWindowEx(
            0,                   /* Extended possibilites for variation */
            L"Window 1",         /* Classname */
            L"Window 1",       /* Title Text */
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD, /* default window */
            0,       /* Windows decides the position */
            0,       /* where the window ends up on the screen */
            600,                 /* The programs width */
            600,                 /* and height in pixels */
            hwnd,        /* The window is a child-window to desktop */
            NULL,                /* No menu */
            hInstance,       /* Program Instance handler */
            NULL                 /* No Window Creation data */
        );
        window2 = CreateWindow(L"STATIC", L"Window 2", WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD, 0, 0, 600, 600, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        button2 = CreateWindow(
            L"BUTTON",
            L"SECOND WINDOW",
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER,
            350, 480,
            200, 20,
            window1, (HMENU)2, NULL, NULL);
        window3 = CreateWindow(L"STATIC", L"Window 3", WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD, 0, 0, 600, 600, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        button3 = CreateWindow(
            L"BUTTON",
            L"THIRD WINDOW",
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER,
            50, 480,
            200, 20,
            window1, (HMENU)3, NULL, NULL);
        ShowWindow(window1, SW_SHOW);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
        break;
    default:                      /* for messages that we don't deal with */
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK windowprocessforwindow1(HWND handleforwindow1, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        switch (wParam) {
        case 2:
            ShowWindow(window1, SW_HIDE);
            ShowWindow(window2, SW_SHOW);
            break;
        case 3:
            ShowWindow(window1, SW_HIDE);
            ShowWindow(window3, SW_SHOW);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:

        return DefWindowProc(handleforwindow1, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```